# How to parse url parameters using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, url

I got these URL parameters:

```
/?sku=123456 & name1=NAME1 & value1=VALUE1 & name2=NAME2 & value2=VALUE2
```

I would like to print them out in HTML using javascript/jQuery in this format:

```
SKU: 123456    
NAME1 : VALUE1
NAME2 : VALUE2
(NAME3 : ...)
```

How does a loop for a variable amount of names/values work?

Comment: What's keeping you?

Comment: Use `split("&")` and `split("=")` to do this work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js)

Comment: Forgot so say that the number of names/values is variable. So name3/value3 etc. ... I don´t know how the loop could work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to parsing string with `&` delimiter. First index of result is `/?sku=123456`. I inserted it into object and remove it from array. Then used `for` to iterating array element and getting value of every element.

```js
var url = "/?sku=123456 & name1=NAME1 & value1=VALUE1 & name2=NAME2 & value2=VALUE2 ";
var params = url.split("&");
var data = {
    "SKU": params[0].split("=")[1]
};
params.splice(0, 1);

for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i+=2){
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        data[params[i].split("=")[1]] = params[i+1].split("=")[1];
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks! What if there are more names/values? (e.g. name3, value3, name4, ...)

Comment: Everything above works, but how can I remove the  "SKU": in line 4? My string already includes "SKU"

Comment: You can don't insert it value to object like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/ad2zb6gc/1/)